# Python - How to read specific line range in a giant text file?

Tags: python, file, range

My task is to read a specific range of lines in a textfile, that was generated in a windows machine via `msinfo32 /report msinfo32.txt` and the contents of this file is GIANT - 2 megabytes of text!

I have to read specific lines and "organize" them in that order, that the hardware info is divided into CPU, OS, Memory and other sections. Right now I need to retrieve network and it's driver information and output it as strings (or a string array).

The generated msinfo32.txt looks like this (shortened version. There are many more sections between that provided piece!):

```
[Keyboard]

Item    Value   
Description USB Input Device    
Name    Enhanced (101- or 102-key)  
Layout  00000409    
Number of Function Keys 12  
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\hidusb.sys (10.0.14393.82, 37.50 KB (38,400 bytes), 20-Nov-16 21:10)    


[Pointing Device]

Item    Value   
Hardware Type   USB Input Device    
Status  OK
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\hidusb.sys (10.0.14393.82, 37.50 KB (38,400 bytes), 20-Nov-16 21:10)    


[Modem]

Item    Value   


[Network]



[Adapter]

Item    Value   
Name    [00000000] Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter   
Adapter Type    Not Available   
Product Type    Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter  
Index   0
Service Name    kdnic   
IP Address  Not Available   
IP Subnet   Not Available   
Default IP Gateway  Not Available   
DHCP Enabled    Yes 
DHCP Server Not Available   
DHCP Lease Expires  Not Available   
DHCP Lease Obtained Not Available   
MAC Address Not Available   
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\kdnic.sys (6.1.0.0, 24.50 KB (25,088 bytes), 16-Jul-16 14:41)   

Name    [00000001] Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller   
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3  
Product Type    Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller  
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_79961462&REV_15\4&1C0E5B7D&0&00E0  
Last Reset  12-May-17 12:54 
Index   1   
Service Name    rt640x64    
IP Address  ???.???.???.???, ????::????:????:????:????  
IP Subnet   255.255.255.0, 64   
Default IP Gateway  ???.???.???.1   
DHCP Enabled    Yes 
DHCP Server ???.???.???.1   
DHCP Lease Expires  23-May-17 02:58 
DHCP Lease Obtained 22-May-17 02:58 
MAC Address ‪??:??:??:??:??:??‬ 
I/O Port    0x0000D000-0x0000D0FF   
Memory Address  0xDF104000-0xDF104FFF   
Memory Address  0xDF100000-0xDF103FFF   
IRQ Channel IRQ 16  
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\rt640x64.sys (9.1.404.2015, 576.00 KB (589,824 bytes), 16-Jul-16 14:41) 


[Protocol]


Item    Value   
Name    Hyper-V RAW 
Connectionless Service  No


[WinSock]

Item    Value   
File    c:\windows\syswow64\wsock32.dll 
Size    16.00 KB (16,384 bytes) 
Version 10.0.14393.0


[Serial]
```

From the provided text file I need to read everything starting from [Network] ending until to [Protocol] excluded.

Right now I am stuck with the following python code:

```
msinfo32 = open("msinfo32.txt")
```

I have google searched for what I need but I only found reading the file line-by-line and importing the entire contents into a variable. But with 2 megabytes I have doubts if python allows containing 2 megabytes of text in a single string variable.

Comment: Just saying that 2MB is not "GIANT".

Comment: 2 megabytes is not large, read your file line by line (`with open('file.txt') as f: for line in f`), and check for the strings you want on each line. Also, your coding attempt barely accounts as an attempt

Comment: as well you must be joking about the code you are stack with. you should at least close the file after using it. but preferred way of-course is using with open statement.

Comment: You might find things easier if you use `msinfo32 /nfo` instead of `/report`, as it generates an XML file, which is going to be easier to read than a free form text document

Comment: @Chris_Rands Are you suggesting, that I should declare a boolean variable as a "flag", which will be true as soon as the line says "[Network]" and false as soon as it is [Protocol] and while the bool is true, the text will be outputted? Seems like an idea!

Comment: @SimonFraser That should work! I have been working for the past few weeks with parsing XML info! Cheers mate!